# PyXNAT Error while importing in python3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed a package pyxnat on python3.4. i have installed required dependencies like httplib2 package and lxml correctly. but still when i import pyxnat i get following error.

```
bash-3.2$ python3.4
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  5 2014, 20:42:22) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pyxnat import Interface
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sdb99/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxnat/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .core import Interface
  File "/Users/sdb99/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxnat/core/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .interfaces import Interface
  File "/Users/sdb99/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxnat/core/interfaces.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .select import Select
  File "/Users/sdb99/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxnat/core/select.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .search import Search
  File "/Users/sdb99/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxnat/core/search.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .errors import is_xnat_error, catch_error
  File "/Users/sdb99/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxnat/core/errors.py", line 31
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestions to correct this?

Thanks!

EDIT:
In python 2.7 i get the following error

```
>>> myXNAT = Interface('https://hd-hni-xnat.cac.berkley.edu:8443/xnat')
User: sdb356
Password: 
(<type 'exceptions.IOError'>, 'interfaces.py', '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sdb99/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxnat/core/interfaces.py", line 228, in __init__
    self._get_entry_point()
  File "/Users/sdb99/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxnat/core/interfaces.py", line 271, in _get_entry_point
    raise e
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I tried looking into interfaces.py to understand the error but wasnt..

Answer (score 0):

You have installed `pyxnat` for **python2** and are trying to import it in the  **python3** interpreter, you have also somehow managed to add your python 2 path to your python 3 path.

Comment: @tryeverylanguage, that simply means you don't have permissions.

Comment: @tryeverylanguage, how did you install python and your packages?

Comment: Cunninghma  Python 2.7 using Homebrew and python 3.4 using installer -pkg file from python website downloads. ...